# What should I do if i forget password in MySQL?

Tags: mysql-5.5

I am using `MySQL5.5`. I trying to login in mysql from terminal by using **"sudo -u root -p"** But i could not remember password.

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html) explains how to reset the root password. The steps are basically the same for Windows and *nix:

1. Stop/kill the MySQL Server process
2. Create a text file, e.g. `~/mysql-init`, containing the following:

> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
>
> Start MySQL using the [`--init-file` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file), using the text file from step 2